# Issues using setappvolume with nircmd

Tags: linux, windows, audio, nircmd

I am using [nircmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/) for a personal group project. I am trying to use the [setappvolume](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setappvolume.html) command to send specific program/process sounds to a sound device other than the default sound device.

This is the format of the command:

```
setappvolume [Process] [volume level] {Device Name/Index}
```

I have tried this:

```
setappvolume Spotify.exe 1 "Speakers"
```

This command doesn't work. However, when I drop the optional command, the function does work:

```
setappvolume Spotify.exe .5
```

The same issue applies to the `changeappvolume` command. Every other listed command that I've tried works. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Or if there is an alternative way to accomplish this, please let me know (Windows or Linux, but preferably Windows).

Comment: Nircmd is for windows not Linux. I had a learning curve with getting it to work with the application i use it for. The best advice I can give is read the chm that comes with it. It will give examples. As far as your specific use you will just have to try random combinations till it works. the documentation is pretty vague and I have found their examples dont apply in every instance such as the formatting of the command wanted to run.

Comment: Have you used the showsounddevices cmd in nircmd to display the devices available so you are targeting the properly named device? i.e. "speakers"

Comment: I understand that NirCmd is for Windows only. I was simply stating that if anyone knew of a way to accomplish this on either a Windows or Linux OS, I would be interested.

What is the chm, and where can I find it?

I have used showsounddevices. I am using the appropriate names. I have also tried using index numbers, and that hasn't worked either (according to the documentation, it should).

Comment: I have found the documentation to be unreliable at times. I am guessing as the software evolved the documentation didnt. The chm is a help file that comes with many programs. It should be in the folder that was downloaded. If not download it again from the site. It may or may not have some other useful suggestions. Its a crap shoot with Nircmd's documentation as you have found out.